# Programmatically change the value of react-select component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using the [react-select](https://react-select.com/home) component in a React app pretty heavily. I've created a wrapper component which allows me to specify a use-case where I want the selected value to reset on selection.

My component wrapper is defined as:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select'
export const SelectComponent = (props) => {
    const selectRef = useRef(null);

    const valueSelected = (item) => {
        if (!item || item.value === props.selectedValue) {
            return;
        }

        if (props.resetOnSelect) {
            selectRef.current.select.clearValue();
        }
        props.onValueSelected(item);
    }

    return <div className="modal-form-row">
        <Select ref={selectRef} options={props.options} onChange={valueSelected} id={props.id} isClearable={true} isSearchable={true} placeholder={props.label} value={props.selectedValue} />
    </div>;
}
```

And this is how the component gets referenced:

```
const options = [
    { label: 'Item1', value: '1' },
    { label: 'Item2', value: '2' },
    { label: 'Item2', value: '2' },
];
<SelectComponent id="select-list" label="Pick an Item" options={options} onValueSelected={this.handleNewItem} value="" resetOnSelect={true} />
```

It appears to be working, as my `valueSelected` handler is called a second time with a null argument, but the select component itself doesn't re-render, it leaves the user's selection showing. Any ideas on what I should try next?

Comment: Can you show the code that wrapper component?

Comment: In your `SelectComponent` you are passing "" as value, so it will never get updated. You need to define `value` as a state and set it to whatever you want whenever you want to change it.

Comment: @ataravati that's the problem I'm facing, I don't want the component to update, I want to capture the selected item in the onChange event handler and leave the select list as empty, but it's not behaving like a true controlled component. The value is remaining at whatever the user selected, hence me trying to manually clear the value in the onChange event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass `null` to the value (or empty string):

```
<Select ... value={ null } />
```

It behaves just like any other contolled component:

- The onChange handler is called with the new value
- the value is set, in this case to `null`

Note that you had set `value` to `props.selectedValue`, which is undefined, and if `value` is undefined (or not given at all), the uncontrolled-component-behavior is used.